# Query dpkg for All Packages Installed/Removed from Default Image

Tags: installation, debian, packages, dpkg, query

Is there any way to query `dpkg` to tell what packages have been added/removed since the base install of a system?

I am running Debian 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell there's not a straight-forward way to do that. `dpkg` database contains only current state of packages so any history would have to be deduced or parsed from logs.

---

### Short answer (aka one-liner for the lazy)

```
dpkg-query -f='${Package}\n' -W  | grep -vx "`grep 'Setting up' /var/log/installer/syslog | cut -d' ' -f8`"
```

### Explanation

#### 1. Getting a list of packages installed by the installer

`debian-installer` writes its logs to `/var/log/installer`. There's a `syslog` file there and we can `grep` that to see what packages were installed:

```
grep 'Setting up' /var/log/installer/syslog
```

Note that we are looking for *Setting up* or *Unpacking* rather than eg. *Selecting* since we want all packages, including those installed as dependencies. We need to extract package names from that:

```
grep 'Setting up' /var/log/installer/syslog | cut -d' ' -f8
```

#### 2. Getting a list of currently installed packages

Now we need a list of currently installed packages to do a `reverse grep` against. We want only package names, eg. no descriptions to avoid filtering out too much so plain `dpkg -l` is not great. We can use `dpkg-query` instead:

```
dpkg-query -f='${Package}\n' -W
```

#### 3. Filtering out packages installed at startup

All that's left to do is to filter out contents of the 1st list from the 2nd list. For that we use `grep -vx`. `-v` is for "reverse", `-x` (or `--line-regex`) is for "exact". The latter only matches whole lines which makes sure that we filter out eg. *apt* but not *aptitude*.

So here's the whole thing put together:

```
 # currently installed
 current="`dpkg-query -f='${Package}\n' -W`"
 # base install (let's also remove duplicates to make verification easier)
 base="`grep 'Setting up' /var/log/installer/syslog | cut -d' ' -f8 | sort | uniq`"
 # your answer
 extra="`echo "$current" | grep -vx "$base"`"
 removed="`echo "$base" | grep -vx "$current"`"
```

#### 4. Verifying results

To check if we got the right packages we can count the lines:

```
 echo "$base" | wc -l         # 160
 echo "$current" | wc -l      # 1677
 echo "$extra" | wc -l        # 1517
 echo "$removed" | wc -l      # 0 (I used "netinst")
```

---

### Update: if `/var/log/installer` is not there

`/var/log/installer` is removed from the system if package `installation-report` is purged. In that case we can get try and get the list of packages that were loaded by the installer from the oldest `/var/log/dpkg.log.*` file.

There's 2 issues with that:

1. there is no guarantee that the info we need is still there since these files are rotated (still there in my case - install on 2010-10-01 and lots of updates since).
2. the oldest file will probably include logs of packages being installed *after* the initial install.

There's nothing we can do about (1). With (2) we can manually (by timestamps perhaps) establish which package concludes the installation by `debian-installer`. In my case it appears to have been `os-prober` (which I believe might be common in some cases due to its relation to `grub`).

Here's example code to get `$base` using this method:

```
 last_installed="os-prober"
 base_dpkglog="`zgrep ' install ' dpkg.log.8.gz | cut -d' ' -f4 | while read pkg; do 
     [ "$pkg" != "$last_installed" ] && echo $pkg || { echo $pkg; break; }
 done | sort | uniq`"
```

And a quick verification:

```
 echo "$base_dpkglog" | wc -l                    # 159
 echo "$base" | wc -l                            # 160
 diff -d <(echo "$base") <(echo "$base_dpkglog") # 31d30
                                                 # < dpkg
```

Comment: this is a great response...only one issue:  I don't have a directory called `/var/log/installer`.  The closest I see is `/var/log/apt/` - and in my case, it's field 3 (not 8) where the package names are.  I'll keep going with this example.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Debian testing/unstable but I think `/var/log/installer` has been there for quite a long time. Perhaps the package `installation-report` has been purged (it removes `/var/log/installer`). I'm not convinced whether `/var/log/apt/*` will list the packages you need as `apt` is not a _required_ package and, as far as I can tell, is not used by the installer (or at least not all along). There is however `/var/log/dpkg` which should have all the entries right from the start - I will update my answer accordingly.